# TCPDF - Internal css not working

Tags: php, tcpdf

When I am using following style then everything works properly.

```
<style>
            table{
                border: 0.5px solid black;
                border-collapse: separate;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            </style>
```

But when Im using class, code is not working.

```
<style>
            .tableWithOuterBorder{
                border: 0.5px solid black;
                border-collapse: separate;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            </style>
```

Following are my details code.

```
$htmlData   =   "<html><head>";
                $htmlData   .=  "<style>
                .tableWithOuterBorder{
                    border: 0.5px solid black;
                    border-collapse: separate;
                    border-spacing: 0;
                }
                </style>";

                $htmlData   .=  "</head><body>";
                $htmlData   .=  "<table class='tableWithOuterBorder'><tr><td>Hello</td><td>Sir</td></tr></table>";
                $htmlData   .=  "</body></html>";

        $pdf->writeHTML($htmlData, true, false, false, false, '');
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: use inline-css instead of internal css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello Change Below line,

```
$htmlData   .=  "<table class='tableWithOuterBorder'><tr><td>Hello</td><td>Sir</td></tr></table>";
```

to

```
$htmlData   .=  '<table class="tableWithOuterBorder"><tr><td>Hello</td><td>Sir</td></tr></table>';
```

Just give class name in double quote("), and everything works properly.

My Final code is right now :

```
$htmlData   =   '<html><head>';
                $htmlData   .=  '<style>
                .tableWithOuterBorder{
                    border: 0.5px solid black;
                    border-collapse: separate;
                    border-spacing: 0;
                }
                </style>';

                $htmlData   .=  '</head><body>';
                $htmlData   .=  '<table class="tableWithOuterBorder"><tr><td>Hello</td><td>Sir</td></tr></table>';
                $htmlData   .=  '</body></html>';
        $pdf->writeHTML($htmlData, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Thanks